# If $ \sum a_n $ is convergent series of nonnegative numbers, can anything be said about $ \sum \frac{a_n}{n} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $ \sum a_n $ is convergent series of nonnegative numbers, can anything be said about $ \sum \frac{a_n}{n} $? I think $ \sum \frac{a_n}{n}  $ is also convergent.

I know that if series  converges then $|r| < 1$ so
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = r < 1 $$

And if we try the same thing for $ \sum \frac{a_n}{n}  $ then:

$$  \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1} \cdotp \frac{n}{a_n} \right| < 1  $$
so we can say that $\sum \frac{a_n}{n} $ converges.

Is that right?

Comment: The series converging tells you that limit is $\le1$, if it exists. You can't conclude strict inequality.

Comment: This could be a more interesting question if the $a_n$ could have any sign and $\sum a_n$ was conditionally convergent but not absolutely convergent

Comment: No, convergence certainly does not imply $|r|=1$, just because the limit defining $r$ need not exist.

Answer (score 4):

Since the $a_n$ are non-negative, we have $\frac{a_n}{n} \leq a_n$ for all $n$. Hence, by the comparison test, $\sum \frac{a_n}{n}$ converges.

Comment: You also know $0 \le \sum \frac{a_n}{n} \le \sum a_n$ by considering partial sums